# Lexical scoping error, property undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My linter warned me about a lexical scoping error in my `reducer`, I moved my declaration out of the `switch` statement like so:

```
export function eventsForMonth(state = {}, action) {
    const { events: {}, day: {} } = action.data;
    const newItems = {};

    switch (action.type) {
        case "EVENTS_MONTH":
            Object.keys(events).map(event => {
                newItems[event] = [...events[event].dots];
            });

            for (let i = -15; i < 85; i++) {
                const time = day.timestamp + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                const strTime = timeToString(time);
                if (!newItems[strTime]) {
                    newItems[strTime] = [];
                }
            }

            return {
                ...newItems
            };

        case "EVENTS_CALENDAR_MONTH": 
            // ...
```

However, now I get an error: cannot read property events of undefined. How can I declare my `events` outside of my `switch` without getting the error?

Comment: check your action.data content, probably error says that data key is undefined

Comment: Hmmm `const { events: {}, day: {} }` ? Did you mean `const { events = {}, day = {} }`?

Comment: Off-topic. Your code is hard to reason about. Why do you use `map` to mutate some external object? Why do you have two loops populating the same object with different data? What are those magic constants 15, 85? Why do you shallow copy `newItems` object before return?

Comment: I'm still learning javascript, it was the best way I could think of to format data from my api.